# Does Heimskr do anything important?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I want to know if killing Heimskr would stop me from getting/finishing any quests or obtaining any items/active effects etc.

Comment: Nope: http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Heimskr

Answer (score 5):

Nope, he's occasionally the target of radiant quests (specifically the Thieves' Guild may ask you to plant evidence at his house), but he himself is pretty worthless.

You may kill him at your leisure.

Alternatively, if his preaching just annoys you, you can mute him [with a mod.](http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/17695/?)